# Disable drag & drop on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, right-click

Let's say you have a website with copyrighted images on it. You definitely do not want anyone to use these, but you also don't want a watermark on every image on your website.

To prevent users from saving my content I have disabled right click using JS:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

and I have disabled drag & drop as well:

```
<html ondragstart="return false;">
```

But then I figured users would be able to turn off JavaScript in their browser and still use those two functions. So I tried the following using CSS (found on this site):

```
html,body {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select:-moz-none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not even work at all... now I'm looking for the best way to turn off the following:

- Text select
- Right click
- Drag & drop

Anyone has suggestions for me?

Comment: keep in mind that loading a page into a browser means loading all the ressources, so whataver you will do we can always get image and text

Comment: Thanks, I understand it. But what is wrong with my CSS? How does it not work?

Comment: Please provide a working example...

Comment: you need to use the universal selector `*` instead of html,body

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't prevent users from copying your images, you can only make it less convenient. So its a matter of deciding how much effort you want to put into this prevention.

You will be able to prevent less sophisticated users via the methods you are using, but any image includes the href (file path on browser). A user could WGET the file, browse directly to the image, open up the Dev Tools, use an analog workaround (like the Windows screen snip tool), etc.

Comment: what you said was already said in comment :) and you are not answering the question at all. He asked about some suggest to how to do this and why his CSS is not working.

Comment: Your initial comment missed the analog hole and didn't address it either...

Comment: because it's a comment :) we are not obliged to redact a complete thing when commenting. But when writing an answer we obliged to write a relevant answer to the question and not simply commenting ;)
By the way the question is off-topic.